# Is this question appropriate for this forum?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to either: draw an analogy between quantum mechanics and real life or get to a point where I'm not able to create an analogy anymore and I give up.  Odds are I'll be in the second boat :-).

My background:  I'm now a Software Engineer.  My coursework was in Computational Mathematics.  I generally like any topic so long that its interesting.  I want to understand where the break between quantum mechanics and my understanding of the world is.

I'm hoping this will be the kind of thing where I will say:  this is my understanding at the high level, and I think this analogy accurately fits what is happening at the quantum level.  Then, someone with actual knowledge about quantum mechanics will say "No, your analogy fails at this point" And they will explain to me why my analogy doesn't correspond to quantum.  Then I will either change my analogy to suite what quantum mechanics says, dispute the point in which they say my analogy doesn't match quantum, or agree that that is correct and I'm unable to create an analogy with the real world to match what is observed at the quantum level.

Is this type of question appropriate for this forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. It sounds like you're looking for a back-and-forth discussion, rather than a specific question that can be answered. You might try [chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), or a more traditional forum where people can reply to you repeatedly.